# Proof that sequence where two entries are the same, then the gcd of these indices must be the step

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to prove the following. 
Assume there is a bit string B = $\{0,1\}^n$, and given that  $ B_i = B_{i+t} $ and $ B_i = B_{i+s} $ for all i < n. then it must hold that $B_i = B_{i+p} $ where p = gcd(s,t)

I cant go any further than this:
 $ B_i = B_{i+t} $,  $ B_i = B_{i+s} $ then
 $ B_i+t = B_{i+s} $ then 
 $ B_{s} = B_{t} $

Comment: The thing you're trying to prove is not actually true. For instance, pick $n, s, t, p$ such that $p < n < s < t$. Then the conditions $B_{i} = B_{i + t}$ and $B_{i} = B_{i+s}$ for all $i$ are vacuously true (you can pick any bit string of length $n$), but $B_i$ and $B_{i+p}$ are not constrained in any way. If that seems too pedantic to you, consider $s = 6$, $t=9$, and $n=10$. Then $p=3$, and you can pick any bit string of the form $\mathsf{abcadeabca}$: that is, the bits at positions 5 and 6 can be arbitrary; they are not forced to be the same as those at positions 1 and 2 (or 8 and 9).

Comment: I did not downvote this BTW; I was just pointing out that you may need to add some more context on where you found the question and whether you're sure you've copied it correctly. Welcome to Math.SE, and hope you have a good time on this site!